# Can't Migrate for the following reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x =>
{
    x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection"), option =>
    {
        option.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext)).GetName().Name);
    });
});
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built.'

When I run the program I get the above error.

However, when trying to migrate, I get the following error

> Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'.

Comment: Do you have IDbOptions parameter in your db context? Or parameterless one

Comment: I have IDbOption parameter inside dbcontext

Comment: It seems you `Build` the application before adding the `Context` to the `ServiceCollection`

Comment: How do I add to service collection ?

Comment: Move the codes you've shown before builder.Build(),the error Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'.  was caused by the failure of  registing the service

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your adding this after builder.Build() has been called, difficult to see without the full code.

Can you try moving it before?